# How do I change image in button after process completion in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a `button` that has an icon set by default. I want to change the icon upon completion of a certain process. The process works but when it comes to changing the image, it says `resource not found`. There is an **images** folder in **Debug**.

I copied and pasted the path that was shown in the error. The path and the file exist yet I am getting the error. Also, the `Build Action` is set to `Resource`.

[image: ePUB WPF image change error]

Button Creation:

```
<Button FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Name="ButtonLoad" Margin="5,9,5,8" Width="70" Background="{x:Null}" Click="ButtonLoad_Click">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Load</Label>
        <Image Source="images/load-file-default.ico" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="19" Width="19"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Button Image Change:

```
string LoadFileUnsuccessful = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"images\load-file-unsuccessful.ico";
if (condition()) //Boolean Function
{
    //Process
}
else
{
    //Process
    ButtonLoad.FindResource(LoadFileUnsuccessful);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Source` of the image to a `BitmapImage` with a [pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf):

```
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/load-file-unsuccessful.ico", UriKind.Absolute));
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Name="ButtonLoad" Margin="5,9,5,8" Width="70" Background="{x:Null}" Click="ButtonLoad_Click">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Load</Label>
        <Image x:Name="img" Source="images/load-file-default.ico" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="19" Width="19"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

For this to work, you should add the images folder to your project and set the `Build Action` of the `.ico` file to `Resource`.

Comment: `System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot locate resource 'images/load-file-unsuccessful.ico'.'` - This is the error I am getting. The file exists in the given path.

Comment: @OmanshuChaurasia: Did you add the images folder to your *project* and set the Build Action to Resource? You can't find a resource in the output folder.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the question. Also, I have updated the question with a screenshot of the same.

Comment: Is ePUBWPF the actual WPF application or is it a referenced library?

Comment: That is the name of the Folder where I have kept my solution. `C:\Users\amanc\source\repos\ePUBWPF\ePUBWPF\bin\Debug`. This is my **FolderPath**

Comment: Absolute file paths don't apply do resources. Again, is ePUBWPF an application or is it a library? If the latter, you should include the assembly name in the pack URI. Please refer to the link I posted for more information.

Comment: It is an application

Comment: Then my sample code should work provided that you haven't misspelled the file or folder name.